# Custom CSS and JS not loaded when running specs with Capybara and Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a test for code which relies on custom javascript. When running app in development environment, everything works like excepted. In test, no custom CSS and JS is included, hence test fails:

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Check your apps test log to see if they're requested, and what responses are set. Secondly, check your test environment config for assets settings, you're not doing something like setting it to get assets from a different server, etc.  Also check what subdirectories you have in public, if you've pre compiled test assets previously it can prevent the asset pipeline from recompiling new changes

Answer (score 6):

In the end I did this:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Somehow assets were not being updated when I was making changes.

Comment: It's because you have a directory where the precompiled test assets are -- delete that directory (usually in public) and then your app should go back to automatically producing the assets on the fly in the test environment

Comment: before I was running `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and it was not working. Thanks for this